# Can FishMox be used for humans as an antibiotic?

Tags: medications

Is it true that the fish antibiotic **FishMox** can be used as an antibiotic by humans?  The advantages would be that it does not require a prescription and is cheaper.

Comment: You can grow penicillin in your kitchen (and most people do unwittingly) as well. So you could just eat the mold you find growing on your bread or cheese, and you'll be taking an unprescribed dose of an antibiotic.  That doesn't mean it's going to be in an effective dose to help you overcome your illness, or that you won't also be consuming other things that may be toxic.

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: I have seen it online in a few places... I first heard of it in a novel... the character urgently needed an antibiotic but was on the run and didn't want to risk exposure by going to a doctor

Answer (score 3):

The active incredient in [fish mox is amoxicillin](http://www.markspetfish.com/fish-mox-medicine-antibiotics/) - which is an antibiotic often prescribed for humans. However, the amoxicillin sold in pet stores [has not been approved for human consumption by the FDA](http://www.everydayhealth.com/health-questions/amoxicillin/is-fish-mox-the-same-as-amoxicillin-and-can-it-be-harmful-to-humans), and there are [adverse effects associated with amoxicillin](http://www.drugs.com/amoxicillin.html). It's best to get a prescription from the Dr. any time you take antibiotics.